# Assigning unique path name in spring webflow while using for each loop

Tags: spring, jstl, spring-webflow

I was using spring textarea to retrieve list of item. The problem doing so is I am getting commas due to repeatition of the path name. How can I make the name of the path name unique? As per my understanding the name of the path should match the variable in the modal.

```
<c:forEach var="note" items="${model.modelname}">
//create a click button for each items
//each click opens up a modal and 

    <div id="modal" class="hidden">
        <div class="modal-body-content">
            <form:textarea path="textPath" />
        </div>
    </div>  

</c:forEach>
```

I tried using specifying index  `<form:textarea path="note[0].textPath" />` but I could not do anything to list the whole item.

I tried giving index to the for each loop and assign unique name to the path as shown below but this just displays the first item on the list

```
<c:forEach var="note" items="${model.modelname}" varStatus="status">
//create a click button for each items
//each click opens up a modal and 

    <div id="modal" class="hidden">
        <div class="modal-body-content">
            <form:textarea path="textPath[${status.index}]" />
        </div>
    </div>  

</c:forEach>
```

Comment: can you post the code of the object containing the notes and then the textpath?

Comment: @rptmat57, note is a list and textpath is a string. Note contains list of string. I tried changing textpath from string to list but that did not help.

Comment: what is holding the list of notes?

Comment: items="${model.modelname}"

Comment: you don't have a "commandName" or "modelAttribute" in your form?

Comment: I just have id and modelAttribute

Comment: what's in your modelAttribute?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151399/discussion-between-mr-and-and-rptmat57).